# After update to Xcode9, I'm getting C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode9

I have a project coded in objective c that uses the SimplePing.h as provided by Apple.

The code was running perfectly until I updated Xcode to v9.0; it's not compiling anymore with an Error in the file SimplePing.h provided by Apple here [SimplePing.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimplePing/Listings/Common_SimplePing_h.html)

> C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

The Error is generated on each of those lines in SimplePing.h

```
check_compile_time(sizeof(IPHeader) == 20);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, versionAndHeaderLength) == 0);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, differentiatedServices) == 1);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, totalLength) == 2);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, identification) == 4);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, flagsAndFragmentOffset) == 6);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, timeToLive) == 8);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, protocol) == 9);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, headerChecksum) == 10);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, sourceAddress) == 12);
check_compile_time(offsetof(IPHeader, destinationAddress) == 16);
```

The Class SimplePing.h includes the following class

```
#include <AssertMacros.h>           // for __Check_Compile_Time
```

in which the code of check_compile_time is defined as below:

```
#ifndef __Check_Compile_Time
    #ifdef __GNUC__ 
        #define __Check_Compile_Time( expr )    \
            extern int compile_time_assert_failed[ ( expr ) ? 1 : -1 ] __attribute__( ( unused ) )
    #else
        #define __Check_Compile_Time( expr )    \
            extern int compile_time_assert_failed[ ( expr ) ? 1 : -1 ]
    #endif
#endif
```

First Question: How can I solve this?
Second Question: I cannot seem to modify the AssertMacros.h file, it is locked.. should i unlock it and fix it? or is there anything else I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: Okay, so the header defines `__Check_Compile_Time`, but it seems `check_compile_time` isn't being defined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to StoryTeller's sharp comment, I just noticed, that Apple modified the name of __check_compile_time to __Check_Compile_Time in the module AssertMacros.h
to fix the problem, update all instances of check_compile_time with __Check_Compile_Time

so the updated code of Apple's SimplePing.h class should be the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#if TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#else
    #import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#endif

#include <AssertMacros.h>

#pragma mark * SimplePing

// The SimplePing class is a very simple class that lets you send and receive pings.

@protocol SimplePingDelegate;

@interface SimplePing : NSObject
{
    NSString *              _hostName;
    NSData *                _hostAddress;
    CFHostRef               _host;
    CFSocketRef             _socket;

    id<SimplePingDelegate>  _delegate;
    uint16_t                _identifier;                            // host byte order
    uint16_t                _nextSequenceNumber;                    // host byte order
}

+ (SimplePing *)simplePingWithHostName:(NSString *)hostName;        // chooses first IPv4 address
+ (SimplePing *)simplePingWithHostAddress:(NSData *)hostAddress;    // contains (struct sockaddr)

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) id<SimplePingDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly)  NSString *             hostName;
@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly)  NSData *               hostAddress;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly)  uint16_t               identifier;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly)  uint16_t               nextSequenceNumber;

- (void)start;
    // Starts the pinger object pinging.  You should call this after 
    // you've setup the delegate and any ping parameters.

- (void)sendPingWithData:(NSData *)data;
    // Sends an actual ping.  Pass nil for data to use a standard 56 byte payload (resulting in a 
    // standard 64 byte ping).  Otherwise pass a non-nil value and it will be appended to the 
    // ICMP header.
    //
    // Do not try to send a ping before you receive the -simplePing:didStartWithAddress: delegate 
    // callback.

- (void)stop;
    // Stops the pinger object.  You should call this when you're done 
    // pinging.

+ (const struct ICMPHeader *)icmpInPacket:(NSData *)packet;
    // Given a valid IP packet contains an ICMP , returns the address of the ICMP header that 
    // follows the IP header.  This doesn't do any significant validation of the packet.

@end

@protocol SimplePingDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address;
    // Called after the SimplePing has successfully started up.  After this callback, you 
    // can start sending pings via -sendPingWithData:

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
    // If this is called, the SimplePing object has failed.  By the time this callback is 
    // called, the object has stopped (that is, you don't need to call -stop yourself).

// IMPORTANT: On the send side the packet does not include an IP header. 
// On the receive side, it does.  In that case, use +[SimplePing icmpInPacket:] 
// to find the ICMP header within the packet.

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet;
    // Called whenever the SimplePing object has successfully sent a ping packet. 

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet error:(NSError *)error;
    // Called whenever the SimplePing object tries and fails to send a ping packet.

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet;
    // Called whenever the SimplePing object receives an ICMP packet that looks like 
    // a response to one of our pings (that is, has a valid ICMP checksum, has 
    // an identifier that matches our identifier, and has a sequence number in 
    // the range of sequence numbers that we've sent out).

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceiveUnexpectedPacket:(NSData *)packet;
    // Called whenever the SimplePing object receives an ICMP packet that does not 
    // look like a response to one of our pings.

@end

#pragma mark * IP and ICMP On-The-Wire Format

// The following declarations specify the structure of ping packets on the wire.

// IP header structure:

struct IPHeader {
    uint8_t     versionAndHeaderLength;
    uint8_t     differentiatedServices;
    uint16_t    totalLength;
    uint16_t    identification;
    uint16_t    flagsAndFragmentOffset;
    uint8_t     timeToLive;
    uint8_t     protocol;
    uint16_t    headerChecksum;
    uint8_t     sourceAddress[4];
    uint8_t     destinationAddress[4];
    // options...
    // data...
};
typedef struct IPHeader IPHeader;

__Check_Compile_Time(sizeof(IPHeader) == 20);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, versionAndHeaderLength) == 0);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, differentiatedServices) == 1);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, totalLength) == 2);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, identification) == 4);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, flagsAndFragmentOffset) == 6);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, timeToLive) == 8);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, protocol) == 9);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, headerChecksum) == 10);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, sourceAddress) == 12);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(IPHeader, destinationAddress) == 16);

// ICMP type and code combinations:

enum {
    kICMPTypeEchoReply   = 0,           // code is always 0
    kICMPTypeEchoRequest = 8            // code is always 0
};

// ICMP header structure:

struct ICMPHeader {
    uint8_t     type;
    uint8_t     code;
    uint16_t    checksum;
    uint16_t    identifier;
    uint16_t    sequenceNumber;
    // data...
};
typedef struct ICMPHeader ICMPHeader;

__Check_Compile_Time(sizeof(ICMPHeader) == 8);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(ICMPHeader, type) == 0);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(ICMPHeader, code) == 1);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(ICMPHeader, checksum) == 2);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(ICMPHeader, identifier) == 4);
__Check_Compile_Time(offsetof(ICMPHeader, sequenceNumber) == 6);
```

Comment: Thanks , Perfect answer